# How do I migrate JBoss 4.0.5 JMS configuration to JBoss EAP 4.3?

Tags: java, jboss, migration, jms

I have a J2EE application running on JBoss 4.0.5 which makes use of custom JMS queues and topics. The configuration for these is in XML files in the `deploy\jms` directory.

JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 4.3, however, does not have a `jms` directory in this location. What do I have to do to migrate my existing JMS configuration files to work on this platform?

Answer (score 0):

JBoss EAP 4.3 uses a completely different JMS implementation (JBoss Messaging) than 4.0.5 (which uses JBossMQ). It's not just a matter of porting configuration, the two systems are very different and may require you to reimplement your JMS client code. Regardless, your config will require a complete rewrite.

Because of this, RedHat still support EAP 4.2, which is the latest version to use JBossMQ, and should make it easy for you to move from JBoss 4.0.5. They still issue patches for EAP 4.2. Basically, if you want to use JBossMQ, you use EAP 4.2, if you want JBossMessaging, use EAP 4.3

Comment: Would I need to reimplement if the code is just using standard JMS APIs? Are there any migration guides which discuss the changes required to the configuration?

Comment: It's still JMS, yes, but it behaves differently, as do all JMS implementations. The EAP documentation should cover the migration path.

Comment: Couldn't find any details of the migration path within the EAP documentation. Any additional help would be appreciated. Thanks.